# Smarty check if URL contains some value

Tags: smarty

I use smarty and I want to check if my currenty URL contains some value.
Therefore I use the following code, but that does not work.

```
{if $smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER|strstr:'domain=transfer&sld='}
```

The full URL;

```
https://example.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=transfer&sld=value&tld=.com
```

What am I missing?

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is the url you came from, not the current one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `REQUEST_URI` instead of `HTTP_REFERER`.

This will do it.